# How to make div section closed on outside click?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have search-suggestions section which is opened when user start search.

That mean when user type something in search input I call `setState({ isSearchActive: true })`

Now when user click outside of that `search-suggestions` div section I would like to call `setState({ isSearchActive: false })``

In parent component I created function `handleClosingSuggestions()`:

```
// this function in called onBlur in child component
  handleClosingSuggestions = (e) => {
      this.setState({ isSearchActive: false });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      searchedQuery, newsList, suggestionsArray, isSearchActive
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <Layout>
        <SearchBar handleSearchChange={this.handleSearchChange} />

        {suggestionsArray.length && searchedQuery.length > 1 && isSearchActive ? (
          <SearchSuggestions
            suggestionsArray={suggestionsArray}

            // PASS DOWN FUNC AS PROPs
            handleClosingSuggestions={this.handleClosingSuggestions}
          />
        ) : (
          ''
        )}
    )
    }
```

And in child component I called `handleClosingSuggestions` func onBlur event on `div wrapper`, but that does not work.

```
export default ({ suggestionsArray, handleClosingSuggestions }) => (

// HERE IS ON BLUR EVENT
  <div className="wrapper" onBlur={handleClosingSuggestions}>
    <div className="suggestions">
      <div className="suggestions-section">
        <SuggestionsList suggestionsArray={suggestionsArray} />
      </div>
      <div className="latest-news-section">
        <LatestNewsList image={testImg} text="McLeish exits as Scotland coach after 12 games" />
      </div>
      <div className="related-trends-section">
        <RelatedTrendsList
          title="Topics"
          option1="Football"
          option2="Tennis"
          iconClass="icon-arrow-up-right2"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

why that on blur event is not triggered and state is not changed?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/30q3mzjv91?module=%2Fsrc%2FOutsideAlerter.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `SuggestionsList` component you can add/remove event listener like this

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClosingSuggestions);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClosingSuggestions);
}
```